# How to decide the location of an image in LaTeX document?

Tags: graphics, tex-core, texstudio

I am new to LaTeX and stuck on this image formatting thing for my algorithms class.
My source looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
    \title{COMP3027 Assignment 1: Greedy Algorithms}
    \maketitle

    \section{Counter-example for the bad algorithm}
     [my text for first section]
        \begin{figure}
           \centering
           \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{fig1} 
        \end{figure}

     \section{Correct Greedy Algorithm}
     \subsection*{(a) Description}

\end{document}
```

It makes this pdf:

my current pdf
[image: my current pdf]

So even though I put the image within the first section, it stays at the bottom of the page, after the second section. **I want the image to be tied to the first section** (called Counter-example for the bad algorithm), so that it ends up near the related text. Is there a way I can do that?

I'm using TexStudio.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are missing floating specifier for your figure. I suggest to use `[htbp]`, which will allow latex to place your image [h]ere, at the [t]op, on the [b]ottom of the page or on an extra [p]age if the other options are not possible.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
    \title{COMP3027 Assignment 1: Greedy Algorithms}
    \maketitle

    \section{Counter-example for the bad algorithm}
     [my text for first section]
        \begin{figure}[htbp]
           \centering
           \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{example-image-duck} 
        \end{figure}

     \section{Correct Greedy Algorithm}
     \subsection*{(a) Description}

\end{document}
```

[image]